# Sonarqube database creation

Tags: mysql, database, installation, sonarqube

A1/ I have installed sonarqube (Versions - 4.0, 4.5.1, 5.1) & configured sonar properties
A2/ Installed Mysql
A3/ Created database sonar, user sonar and granted privileges.

A4/Sonarqube works perfectly fine.
when I try to access http://localhost:9000/setup it says "Database is up-to-date. "

but when I follow the link http://www.sonarqube.org/screencasts2/installation-of-sonar/ I am getting error "unable to connect to database"

the steps I performed are 
1/ installed sonarqube and configured mysql JDBC URL, user, password, and sonarport.
2/ installed and started mysql (have not created database 'sonar' and user 'sonar')
3/ launched setup url ( please see step A3 for the URL, as I can not post more than 2 links)

I am getting error (unable to connect to database) instead of the "setup database" screen showed in the video.

can you please throw some more pointers on how to setup mysql database for sonarqube as shown in the video?

Answer (score 1):

Allright Raj, maybe SonarSource did not precise 'database schema' in this screen, but the way to do it is 
1. install database like MySQL or Oracle
2. create a database user, like indicated here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing#Installing-installingDatabaseInstallingtheDatabase

Once you have installed SonarQube, the page you see in the video is where it will install the whole schema, tables and other database objects, on the user you have previously created.

If you want some help on installing and configuring SonarQube, I have a whole section about it on my blog http://qualilogy.com/en/category/sonar/sonar-installation/

Don't hesitate to ask for precision.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight. I have browsed through lot of pages but I am unable to reach to the position of "setup database" screen as shown in the video. when I created database and user - sonar does create rest of tables. All good. when I say http://localhost:9000/setup, it responds with database is unto date. Can you help in reaching the page "setup database" ? I have been trying to get to the stage since 2 months.

Comment: Could anyone throw some light on this so called "database setup"?

Answer (score 0):

As it's a fresh installation, you need to create first the database sonar and user sonar. Please be sure you can connect to it before trying to start SonarQube. Be sure to follow requirements for MySQL : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements
Once the database is ready, start SonarQube and it will create the tablee, index, ...
In the video we suppose the database is already created and we don't believe this part is specific to SonarQube installation.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks for your response. prerequisite says "The only prerequisite for running SonarQube is to have Java (Oracle JRE 7 onwards or OpenJDK 7 onwards) installed on your machine."  I am unable to attach the screenshot, but from the video at 1min 14 secs, it shows a screen with details "Sonar setup, create database and setup database". from this I believe that there is a way in sonar to create database and not through manual creation. Any pointers are help is highly regarded.

Answer (score 0):

Raj,

SonarQube does not create the database automatically. 
It would need a specific creation script for each database as you don't create a database for Oracle or MySQL or SQLServer or ... in the same way. 
The parameters of the DB would also change according to the environment: I can have DBA privileges on a DB on my laptop but I sysadmins will let you have them on a DB in production.

Comment: Hi, from the video http://www.sonarqube.org/screencasts2/installation-of-sonar/ at 1min 14 secs, it shows a screen with details "Sonar setup, create database and setup database". Can you please check and advise? I have searched in internet about this database creation but no luck.